# PHP Regex for human names

Tags: php, regex, names

I've run into a bit of a problem with a Regex I'm using for humans names.

```
$rexName = '/^[a-z' -]$/i';
```

Suppose a user with the name Jürgen wishes to register? Or Böb? That's pretty commonplace in Europe. Is there a special notation for this?

EDIT:, just threw the Jürgen name against a regex creator, and it splits the word up at the ü letter...

http://www.txt2re.com/index.php3?s=J%FCrgen+Blalock&submit=Show+Matches

EDIT2: Allright, since checking for such specific things is hard, why not use a regex that simply checks for illegal characters?

```
$rexSafety = "/^[^<,\"@/{}()*$%?=>:|;#]*$/i";
```

(now which ones of these can actually be used in any hacking attempt?)

For instance. This allows ' and - signs, yet you need a ; to make it work in SQL, and those will be stopped.Any other characters that are commonly used for HTML injection of SQL attacks that I'm missing?

Comment: Just don’t validate that datum.

Comment: I've been wondering about this too...

Comment: I agree with @Gumbo, there's probably not a good reason to validate the characters in a name. A more appropriate solution might be to run the field against a blacklist regular expression, rather than trying to accept a whitelist of valid characters. What happens when 陳 tries to submit your form? Are you going to have a regular expression with every single international character in it? :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would really say : don't try to validate names : one day or another, your code will meet a name that it thinks is "wrong"... And how do you think one would react when an application tells him "*your name is not valid*" ?

Depending on what you really want to achieve, you might consider using some kind of blacklist / filters, to exclude the "not-names" you thought about : it will maybe let some "bad-names" pass, but, at least, it shouldn't prevent any existing name from accessing your application.

Here are a few examples of rules that come to mind :

- no number
- no special character, like `"~{()}@^$%?;:/*§£ø` and probably some others
- no more that 3 spaces ?
- none of "admin", "support", "moderator", "test", and a few other obvious non-names that people tend to use when they don't want to type in their real name...

  - (but, if they don't want to  give you their name, their still won't, even if you forbid them from typing some random letters, they could just use a real name... Which is not their's)

Yes, this is not perfect ; and yes, it will let some non-names pass... But it's probably way better for your application than saying someone "your name is wrong" *(yes, I insist ^^ )*

And, to answer a comment you left under one other answer :

> I could just forbid the most command
>   characters for SQL injection and XSS
>   attacks,

About SQL Injection, you must escape your data before sending those to the database ; and, if you always escape those data (you should !), you don't have to care about what users may input or not : as it is escaped, always, there is no risk for you.

Same about XSS : as you always escape your data when ouputting it (you should !), there is no risk of injection ;-)

---

**EDIT :** if you just use that regex like that, it will not work quite well :

The following code :

```
$rexSafety = "/^[^<,\"@/{}()*$%?=>:|;#]*$/i";
if (preg_match($rexSafety, 'martin')) {
    var_dump('bad name');
} else {
    var_dump('ok');
}
```

Will get you at least a warning :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '{'
```

You must escape at least some of those special chars ; I'll let you dig into [PCRE Patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) for more informations *(there is really a lot to know about PCRE / regex ; and I won't be able to explain it all)*

If you actually want to check that none of those characters is inside a given piece of data, you might end up with something like that :

```
$rexSafety = "/[\^<,\"@\/\{\}\(\)\*\$%\?=>:\|;#]+/i";
if (preg_match($rexSafety, 'martin')) {
    var_dump('bad name');
} else {
    var_dump('ok');
}
```

*(This is a quick and dirty proposition, which has to be refined!)*

This one says "OK" *(well, I definitly hope my own name is ok!)*

And the same example with some specials chars, like this :

```
$rexSafety = "/[\^<,\"@\/\{\}\(\)\*\$%\?=>:\|;#]+/i";
if (preg_match($rexSafety, 'ma{rtin')) {
    var_dump('bad name');
} else {
    var_dump('ok');
}
```

Will say "bad name"

But please note I have **not** fully tested this, and it probably needs more work ! Do not use this on your site unless you tested it very carefully !

Also note that a single quote can be helpful when trying to do an SQL Injection... But it is probably a character that is legal in some names... So, just excluding some characters might no be enough ;-)

Comment: Yes, it will be escaped... but still entered into the database. I wouldn't like it if there were a couple hundred profiles on my website displaying nothing but a bunch of SQL code...

Comment: In this case, it might be interesting to add some words like "select", "update", "delete", "where", "order by" and such stuff to the blacklist of forbidden words ; afterall, it is almost certain that they are not used in names ;-) ; And you might also want to ensure that a user cannot register too many times (a -- not necessarily the best one -- quite basic idea might be to set a limit on the number of registrations that can come from a single IP adresse in one hour, for instance)

Comment: Updated the original post with rexSafety variable.

Comment: Perhaps a better question to ask myself is: which characters do hackers ALWAYS need? For instance, I can allow the single quote and minus sign, but I will forbid = @ and ; The idea being a string meant to get past the security, will never be a single character. So it's a process of elimination: what is commonplace in human names and what is not. I don't need to forbid the ' character, since it will always be in the company of a @ or = sign. That's not 100% true, but I hope you see what I'm getting at.

Comment: The only problem with not allowing symbols: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_%28musician%29

Answer (score 7):

[PHP’s PCRE implementation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) supports [Unicode character properties](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.unicode) that span a larger set of characters. So you could use a combination of `\p{L}` (letter characters), `\p{P}` (punctuation characters) and `\p{Zs}` (space separator characters):

```
/^[\p{L}\p{P}\p{Zs}]+$/
```

But there might be characters that are not covered by these character categories while there might be some included that you don’t want to be allowed.

So I advice you against using regular expressions on a datum with such a vague range of values like a real person’s name.

---

**Edit**   As you edited your question and now see that you just want to prevent certain code injection attacks: You should better escape those characters rather than rejecting them as a potential attack attempt.

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for SQL queries, [`htmlspecialchars`](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars) for HTML output and other appropriate functions for other languages.

Comment: I don't only want to prevent code injection, I don't even want escaped code to ever enter the database. As I already stated: imagine a user-profile website(myspace for instance). Imagine coming across a profile ridden with SQL injections. All of them escaped... What the hell kind of service is that? Why would I allow hackers to fill my database with useless dribble like that, when the only thing they're trying to do is hack my website?

Answer (score 4):

That's a problem with no easy general solution. The thing is that you really can't predict what characters a name could possibly contain. Probably the best solution is to define an negative character mask to exclude some special characters you really don't want to end up in a name.

You can do this using:

$regexp = "/^[**^***<put unwanted characters here>*]+$/

Comment: So if I can't predict the characters, wouldn't it be better to use a regex that disallows things instead one that allows things? I could just forbid the most command characters for SQL injection and XSS attacks, which would allow things like ü.

Comment: No, don't filter for SQL keywords and similar things. That's extremely bad coding style. Instead, escape data properly. Use mysql_realescape() to prevent SQL injections and htmlentities() for XSS attacks.

Comment: Yes, sebasgo is right on. This is a waste of your time if you're trying to prevent SQL injections. Use functions designed for this purpose, don't reinvent the wheel :P

Comment: "That's extremely bad coding style". That makes no sense. Adding a couple of characters to a blacklisting regex can't be called "extremely bad coding style". I can understand if you favor using the functions you mentioned, but don't go saying that people who do different have an "extremely bad coding style"

Comment: If you filter SQL keywords, the poor Bobby Tables will not be able to attend school.

Comment: Also, the mysql_real_escape_string() function simply turns potentially harmful code into a dud. It makes it harmless... but it's still entered into the database and I don't want that. Imagine that on a profile site where a user profile display a whole bunch of SQL code...

Comment: I read XKCD, Stefano.Also, I'm not filtering keywords at all, I'm filtering symbols. A hacker can put in as many keywords as he/she wants, if the ; symbol is found in the string, then it won't matter, it'll be refused.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to parse apart a human name in PHP, I recomment [Keith Beckman's nameparse.php script](http://jonathonhill.net/2009-10-31/human-name-parsing-in-php/).