# Blacklist regular expression to validate human name in any language

Tags: regex, validation, unicode, struts-1, struts-validation

I am using Struts 1.3.1 validator (validation.xml, using mask and regular expression), which doesn't support Unicode regular expressions.
(I [read](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Validation-quot-Mask-quot-unicode-characters-td3490299.html) and I [tried](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html))

When it's a whitelist, and unicode, it should be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261338/php-regex-for-human-names):

```
^[\p{L}\p{P}\p{Zs}]+
```

Yet, in my case, I need to filter all "helping characters" and leave out letters only.

Does anyone have an idea of a blacklist regular expression to answer my needs?

I though of this one, but it obviously doesn't cover everything:

```
^[^&amp;^&gt;^/^&lt;^\\^*^\?^%^:]$
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are "helping characters"? Are you basically saying you want to match unicode letters?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to match all unicode letters, without using the unicode stuff that isn't supported in struts.

Comment: The character class you wrote is actually `[^aglmpt/:;\\*?%^&]`, because character class treat a 'string' as a set of char. Use negative lookahead instead, like `(?!^&amp;|^&gt;|^/|^&lt;|^\\|^*|^\?|^%|^:)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't understand the equality your presented davide, I also edited my original expression a bit as I had some typo there).

Comment: You generally shouldn't be doing string manipulations on the HTML-encoded form of a value—validate it raw first, do the HTML-escaping later. Also you have `\p{P}` in your target whitelist and that includes all the characters you're trying to exclude, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: bobince, I cannot use \p{P}, as struts validator doesn't support that (at least in the version I need to use).
So I am trying to filter out bad inputs, that's all. I din't do any string manipulation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you appear to be trying to exclude `&amp;`, but you won't have HTML-escaped input unless you have specifically escaped it yourself for some reason (there are reasons people do sometimes HTML-escape all input, but they are very bad reasons). As for `\p{P}` it would *allow* all the characters `&>/<\*?%`—is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I chose in the end:

Note! this is Struts 1.3.1 syntax for a validator mask!

```
^[^&amp;&gt;&lt;\\*?%:!&quot;#$()+,;=@\[\]{}~\^|`\n\t\r/]+$
```

Disallowing special characters, allowing others.

This was considered as a white-list approach, but was neglected as it needed work (adding other languages other than European and Japanese/Chinese):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-'àÀâÂäÄáÁéÉèÈêÊëËìÌîÎïÏòóÒôÔöÖùúÙûÛüÜçÇ’ñß]+|[一-龠]+|[ぁ-ゔ]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[々〆〤]+$
```